# How to convert datetime format in sql to datetime in java[eclipse]

Tags: java, sql, datetime

I am trying to retrieve values from a database.

In the database I have a column called `trip_time` which is in date time format "2014-10-13 08:30:00".

I am not able to set and get the values for `trip_time` in eclipse.

What is the similar format in java which matches with database?

In the database it is in datetime format 2014-10-13 08:30:00.
Now currently in eclipse i am using String format for the column trip_time.
How do i convert it to datetime format as in sql database?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't have a specific way.  You're talking in terms of Java here, right?  If you've got code, would you mind sharing it?

Comment: Please add more detail ... how are you retrieving the data? Is the column a datetime type or text formatted as datetime ... give the community the detail they need to help you.

Comment: Got to know my problem.thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 1):

public class DateTime {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Get the value from database, using the steps to connect and get the value


    java.sql.Date trip_time= //"{Collected value from DB}"; 
    //"2014-10-13 08:30:00"; //Assume u got this value

    //Now it's time to convert to Sql date time to java data time

    java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date(trip_time.getTime());
    System.out.println("Converted value of java.util.Date : " + utilDate);  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now currently in eclipse i am using String format for the column trip_time.

No this is not what you want to do, this is not what you should do!

Please use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to get and set values for SQL-Statements. For date fields just use the [setDate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate(int,%20java.sql.Date)) method and pass it a [java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), It will take care of everything for you.

Please refer to [oracle's tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) on this topic.

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-insert-date-value-in-preparedstatement/) another one with code example for date fileds.